# Toshiba 1TB usb external hard drive not recognized

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a Toshiba 1TB external hard drive. Somebody used it (on Windows) and suddenly stopped working. I tried to mount in on my pc (ubuntu 14.04) and it didn't work, so it is not recognized on Windows or Linux.

I changed the USB cable. Didn't work.
I extracted the disk from the case and tried with another case. Didn't work.

`parted -l` gives me this information:

```
Model: TOSHIBA MK1059GSM (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt


Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name Flags

 1      17,4kB  134MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
```

And nothing more. It at least shows some information about the disk, so I hope it is not completely lost.

Can anybody help me to solve this? (I have a lot of information there, so I do not want to format the disk).

*EDIT*:

1. I don't have a Windows machine.
2. By "doesn't work" I mean that the disk is not mounted after being connected and I can't access my files.

Comment: Clarification required: Does it work in Windows now or doesn't? It could be hypothesized that the last usage in Windows somehow activated "dynamic disks", a Microsoft's proprietary technology not compatible with Linux distros. That being the case, however, the drive would still work in Windows. If it now doesn't, that suggests hardware failure.

Comment: No it doesn't work on Windows @CelticWarrior

Comment: So please **define** "doesn't work" by editing your question. Is it recognized (in Windows) but doesn't show a drive letter? Please check "disk management". Does it shows the drive but with unrecognized file systems in one or more partitions? Or not at all? If the latter then it's hardware failure therefore nothing to do with the OSes.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I don't have a Windows Machine, so that's why I'm asking here. For "doesn't work" I mean the disk is not mounted after being connected and I can't access my files. As you can see from my question it is still not completely lost because `parted` shows some information. So apologies for not using the _perfect_ terms in my question. Can you help?

Comment: Nothing to add to my previous comment. There are only two possibilities and you have to troubleshoot. In Ubuntu, for a better (and visual) understanding of the situation, use Disks or GParted. How does the partitions show up in either of this tools? Also, with Disks you can check the drive's health.